# How do I add a constraint for two values in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a "friend database" where a form inserts two values to the table, `friend` consisting of `uid1` and `uid2`, the sender and receiver. The problem is that you can do this multiple times, so you would have more than one of the same friend.

I've tried to add some constraints, but it doesn't seem to work. I have a theory it might conflict with the `id` column which also is a unique and primary value, and that's where the confusion spread.

Answer (score 0):

You want a compound primary key:

```
create table friends (
    uid1 int,
    uid2 int,
    primary key (uid1, uid2)
);
```

Or a compound unique key, if you already have a primary key:

```
create table friends (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    uid1 int,
    uid2 int,
    unique (uid1, uid2)
);
```

Depending on your use case, it might be helpful to have a check constraint that prevents "mirror" records (like `(1, 2)` vs `(2, 1)`:

```
create table friends (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    uid1 int,
    uid2 int,
    unique (uid1, uid2),
    check(uid1 < uid2)
);
```